# GraphQL - Unknown directive "unique"

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I just updated GraphQL from version 0.13.2 to 14.0.2. When starting the server, I get the error message: `Error: Unknown directive "unique"`. This is my schema:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')

// type Query is the root query
exports.typeDefs = gql`
type User {
    username: String! @unique
    password: String!
}

type Query {
    getAllUsers: User
}
```

Note even though I'm using `gql` from `apollo-server` it's using GraphQL under the hood.

As you can see what is causing is the issue is that I've made it so the username has to be unique. The updated version of GraphQL must not have this directive anymore. Sure enough, removing `@unique` solves the issue. I still want username to be unique. I've read that you can create custom directives. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: The `@unique` directive is specific to certain products like Prisma, which extend the basic functionality provided by GraphQL.js. It's not part of the GraphQL.js module, so upgrading that wouldn't make a difference. Are you using Prisma or some other layer on top of GraphQL (outside of Apollo server)?

Comment: If not, what behavior are you trying to introduce with a `@unique` directive? Unless your type definitions are used to create an underlying database schema, which is what tools like Prisma do, then it's unclear what declaring a field as "unique" would actually do in terms of how GraphQL requests are resolved.

Comment: @avatarhzh did you find any solution for this? I'm also stuck with this issue.

Comment: @Progeeker no I just removed `@unique` from the schema. I'm using Mongoose/MongoDB and so just required username to be unique with the Mongoose model.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar scenario to yours when working in fully custom directives with the upgrade of graphql-tools to v14 the definition of the directive is needed within the schema. You can specify by field, object, mutation where your directive will work.

```
directive @requireAuth on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

To work in something like this, at field level

```
extend type Query {
  me: String! @requireAuth
  user(userId: ID!):User!    
  users: [User]!  
}
```

And my class that extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor it's something like this

```
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from "apollo-server";

export class YourCustomDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    // Your code for the directive 
}
```

In the link provided, there is the available methdos to use in order to have your custom logic at field, object, scalar, etc level. Hope this helps.

[Schema Directive Visitor](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives.html#Implementing-schema-directives)